# Update a WPF label using Binding

Tags: wpf

On my wpf application, I’m trying to update a label whenever a certain variable changes in my ViewModel.  Do you know why the label won’t update?

Here’s what I have at the moment:

xaml

```
<Label Name="myLabel" Content="{Binding myState}" />
```

myViewModel.cs

in the constructor:

```
_MyObject.myEvent += myNewEvent;
```

and later...

```
private void myNewEvent(object sender, myArgs e)
{
    myState = someStringVariable;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your ViewModel doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged.
If you want the UI to reflect changes of properties in the ViewModel, the Viewmodel must implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` *and* raise a `PropertyChanged` event in the property's setter whenever the value is changed.

For more information:
**[How to: Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

Likely, you need to set set the `DataContext` of the element that contains this label to the instance of your type which I assume `_MyObject` represents. If you've done that already, it should update whenever you change the property value.